# proxy servers with ips from various other countries

Tags: proxy, ubuntu-12.04, centos-6, squid, socks-proxy

I am trying to setup a proxy server for a few members of my team.
I want to give it to them through my VPS server, what I want to know is I want to give
at least 30 IPs from different country then next 30 from another country and so one.What I am not clear with is from where can I get IPs and in this case what should be my approach to setup the server.Since I have only have experienced with squid as a proxy on linux and in that I just had to give my server IP and NAT the connection but in this case I myself want my users to have some IP which should be different than mine.

Answer (score 0):

IPv4 addresses are a very rare commodity. Getting multiple blocks of 30 IPs will be next to impossible (and/or very very expensive). You will probably have to look into TOR, which is slow and can cause security issues, but will allow you to make outgoing TCP connections from around 3000+ IPs around the world. You can select the exit node manually; consult the TOR manual for more information.

Comment: Ok I want to know if I want to buy IP address then what is a way to do so who sells IP addresses if I want start an ISP that is what I want to know

Comment: No offence, but if you have to ask questions like this, you lack a lot of knowledge required for starting an "ISP". This looks very much like you want to start a VPN/Proxying service. Watch out for legal matters, because you do not want your name to be associated with an IP address that gets abused for crime. To get an IP address assigned to you, you will need to provide a valid reason. See e.g. [this description](http://faq.hosteurope.de/view.php?mode=drucken&content_id=287) (scroll down for english)